# How to let a user join channel in Slack App

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am working on a slack app which has its bot also.A user can share a file from the bot to any public channel even if he is not in that channel. If user is not in the channel then firstly I will add the user in the channel and then share the file. For this slack provides api https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join which helps a user join a channel. But it expects a user token corresponding to the user who wants to join the channel. Now the issue is I only have bot token(xoxb-) and api token(xoxp-) corresponding to the user which has installed the app. So how can I get the token corresponding to any user whom I want to join OR I am missing something here. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need a token corresponding with the joining user.

When installing a Slack app with a bot user you receive two tokens: a bot token and an app token. The app token (but not the bot token) will work for inviting users to public channels, provided your app has the required scopes ([`channels:write`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:write)).

Comment: But channels.join API takes only token and name of the channel to join then how does it will determine which user I want to join, it does not take any user name or user id to determine this.

Comment: I think for letting a user join a channel API is channels.invite not channels.join as channels.invite takes user id as parameter to let a user join the public channel. Is my understanding correct Erik?

Comment: yes, you are correct. use `channels.invite` together with the app token to invite users to a channel.

Comment: Thanks @Erik thats worked. But one problem that I am seeing is that It is showing "@username"(User who has installed the app) has invited when user joined a channel with channels.invite but I want it should show "@botname" has invited what to do for this?

Comment: I see your point. Unfortunately that is how Slack works and its not possible to show the botname. However there is a workaround: I use a generic admin user (mine is called "slackadmin") as installer, so then it shows "invited by slackadmin".